# Changing the action that the X button makes in PyQT

Tags: pyqt4

In the script im doing, im using processes, so when I close the GUI using the x button, I have some zombies, I have a method to kill all when the close button is clicked so I need to make the event of the x button to call this method, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to subclass the [closeEvent](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#closeEvent) of your window, call your function and then accept the event.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    kill_zombies()
    event.accept()
```

It would be nice if you update the user that the cleanup process is ongoing if it'll take a few seconds. Some users react badly to a close button that doesn't close right away and will just kill your app before the zombies have been zapped.